# Как программно задать отступы для view от других view?

Tags: java, android

У меня по кнопке создаётся новый элемент в ConstraintLayout. Как задать ему отступы от другого view? (n изначально равна 8);

```
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                n++;
                ConstraintLayout laybridge = findViewById(R.id.laybridge);
                EditText newEditText = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
                EditText name8 = findViewById(R.id.name8);
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = name8.getLayoutParams();
                newEditText.setLayoutParams(params);
                newEditText.setEms(10);
                newEditText.setMaxLines(40);
                newEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.for_input);
                newEditText.setTextAppearance(R.style.ETon2Layout);
                int name_id = laybridge.getResources().getIdentifier("name".concat(String.valueOf(n)), "id", getPackageName());
                newEditText.setId(name_id);
                newEditText.setTypeface(BeauSansPro);
                laybridge.addView(newEditText);
            }

        });
```

edittext от которого должен зависеть новый

```
<EditText
                    android:id="@+id/name8"
                    style="@style/ETon2Layout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/for_input"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLength="40"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name7"
                    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".32" />
```

а параметры нового должны получиться

```
<EditText
                    android:id="@+id/name9"
                    style="@style/ETon2Layout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/for_input"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLength="40"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name8"
                    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".32" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Самый легкий способ, для того чтобы придать отступ элементу EditText, нужно вместе с ним создать LinearLayout потом этому элементу задать отступ

```
TextView[] btn = new TextView[5];
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        btn[i] = new TextView(this);
        btn[i].setId(i);
        btn[i].setPadding(10,10,10,10);
        btn[i].setHeight(height);
        btn[i].setTextSize(20);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        llp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, margins); // llp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
        btn[i].setLayoutParams(llp);
        btn[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_edit_text);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 17) {
            btn[i].setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.english,0,0,0);
        }
        btn[i].setText("dynamic TextView " + i);
        linearLayout.addView(btn[i]);
        btn[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.relatived),"You have Clicked",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```